# Как переместить элемент RecyclerView на самый верх

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

Я создаю приложение Заметки и хочу что-бы при нажатии на звездочку (избранное) эта заметка переместилась на самый верх.

[image: Скрин]

NoteAdapter.java

```
package com.vitaliy.notes.Adapters;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.vitaliy.notes.Interfaces.SetOnClickItem;
import com.vitaliy.notes.Models.Note;
import com.vitaliy.notes.R;

import java.util.List;

public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Note> noteList;
    private final SetOnClickItem setOnClickItem;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static boolean flug = false;

    public NoteAdapter(List<Note> noteList, SetOnClickItem setOnClickItem, Context context) {
        this.noteList = noteList;
        this.setOnClickItem = setOnClickItem;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    public void setFilteredList(List<Note> filteredList) {
        this.noteList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_note_model, parent, false));
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Note note = noteList.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(note.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(note.getDescription());
        holder.date_of_creation.setText(note.getDate_of_creation());

        holder.btn_star_note.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (flug) {
                holder.btn_star_note.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_no_star);
                flug = false;
            } else {
                holder.btn_star_note.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_yes_star);
                flug = true;
            }
        });

        // Обработка нажатия на элемент RecyclerView
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> setOnClickItem.onClick(note));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noteList.size();
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Объекты модели
        final TextView title, description, date_of_creation;
        final ImageButton btn_star_note;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            date_of_creation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            btn_star_note = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_star_note);
        }
    }
}
```

item_model_note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/Box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_star_note"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_no_star" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hint_title"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_star_note"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hint_desc"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_star_note"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hint_date"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_star_note"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Внесите признак `isFavorite` в `Note`, и иконку отображайте в зависимости от этого признака.
2. Далее при клике на звезду, вам нужно мутировать данные, а не менять ui:

   ```
   public NoteAdapter(FavToggleListener favToggleListener,...){
       this.favToggleListener = favToggleListener;
       ...
   }
   holder.btn_star_note.setOnClickListener(v-> favToggleListener.toggleFav(note));
   ```
3. В этом обработчике меняете `note.isFavorite`, создаете новый массив на основе старого с правильным порядком (сортируете, например)
4. Передаете массив в `adapter.setFilteredList()`

ЗЫ По поводу `@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")` Будет лучше, если вы будете использовать `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`, который избавит вас от кучи проблем, связанных со скоростью обновления, с анимациями при добавлении/удалении и т.д.

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо)